# Serialize redis data with node

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, redis

I am using redis and node (with [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis)) and I would like to serialize data from redis into an XML file (using [simple-xml-writer](https://github.com/minchenkov/simple-xml-writer)), but I stumble upon the asynchronous behavior of node.

I have datasets for a,b,c,d and e stored as a hash in redis, the keys are data:a, data:b data:c ... and each key accesses a hash. Now my XML file should look like this:

```
<root>
  <data record="a">
     (data for a)
  </data>
  <data record="b">
     (data for b)
  </data>
  ...
</root>
```

My approach is to do something like:

```
myobjects = Array.new();
["a","b","c","d","e"].forEach(function(str) {
   database.hmget("data:" + str,function(err,obj){ myobjects.push(obj) });
});
now_serialize_myobjects();
```

Is it possible to wait for the `forEach`-loop to finish *and* be sure all objects in `database.hmget()` are stored? So when calling the function `now_serialize_myobjects()`, all objects covered?

What is the best approach to that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest approach

```
myobjects = Array.new();
var something = ["a","b","c","d","e"]; 
something.forEach(function(str) {
   database.hmget("data:" + str,function(err,obj){ 
     myobjects.push(obj);
     if(myobjects.length === something.length){
        now_serialize_myobjects();
     }
 });
});
```

But why not serialize as requests return?

```
 startxmlfile();
 var something = ["a","b","c","d","e"]; 
 var completionCounter = 0;
 something.forEach(function(str) {
   database.hmget("data:" + str,function(err,obj){ 
     completionCounter++;
     if (!err)
        serialize(obj);
     if (completionCounter ===something.length)
        finalizexmlfile();

 });
});
```

if you are loading a ton of stuff second one is better I think

Comment: Good idea. I am now using #1, but I see the advantage of #2. Thanks!